# ADLDAP2 for Laravel 5.2 - Binding user to model

Tags: php, laravel-5, adldap

This is my first time using ADLDAP & I've only done some Laravel work, so I'm getting confused.

The notes in the config file say this:

```
    /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Bind User to Model
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The bind user to model option allows you to access the Adldap user model
| instance on your laravel database model to be able run operations
| or retrieve extra attributes on the Adldap user model instance.
|
| If this option is true, you must insert the trait:
|
|   `Adldap\Laravel\Traits\AdldapUserModelTrait`
|
| Onto your User model configured in `config/auth.php`.
|
| Then use `Auth::user()->adldapUser` to access.
|
| This option must be true or false.
|
*/
```

My question is where/how do I add the `Adldap\Laravel\Traits\AdldapUserModelTrait` trait in the config/auth.php file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use it inside your auth configuration file. But you import it in your user model. So

```
use Adldap\Laravel\Traits\AdldapUserModelTrait;

class User extends Authenticatable {
    use AdldapUserModelTrait;
}
```

Comment: That makes more sense. It was the wording in the comment of `insert the trait...Onto your User model configured in config/auth.php` that confused me. thanks!

Comment: Author of Adldap2 here. I'll change the wording to make it clearer, thanks for the suggestion!